# How to suppress "ignoring SIGPIPE signal" error message in R?

Tags: r, signals

I have the following files.

- `main.R`

  ```
  x=data.frame(x=seq_len(100000))
  write.table(x, file=stdout(), row.names=F, col.names=F)
  ```
- `main.sh`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  Rscript main.R | head
  ```

I got the following error `ignoring SIGPIPE signal`. This is against the common Linux convention (usually the SIGPIPE signal is ignored). Is there a way to disable such error message in R?

```
$ ./main.sh
R> # vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:
R> x=data.frame(x=seq_len(100000))
R> write.table(x, file=stdout(), row.names=F, col.names=F)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
  ignoring SIGPIPE signal
Calls: write.table
Execution halted
```